# How to replace value of input with userEvent in react jest test

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-testing-library, user-event

When using `userEvent.type` in react the value is appended to the current inputs value.
How can I replace the current value / clear the input using userEvent?

I have tried to use `{backspace}` and `{selectall}` tokens but they have no effect.
Do I have to manually reset the inputs value?

```js
await userEvent.type(input, "1"); // 1
await userEvent.type(input, "123"); // 1123

// I can manually reset value using .value setter though
input.value = "";
await userEvent.type(input, "123"); // 123
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Selects the text inside an input or textarea and deletes it.

https://testing-library.com/docs/ecosystem-user-event/#clearelement

```
await userEvent.clear(input);
```

Comment: Dont know how I missed that...

Comment: Why are you using `await` when `userEvent.clear()` does not return a `Promise`

Comment: The [docs](https://testing-library.com/docs/user-event/utility#clear) show it returning a promise.